# Python, text mining, docx to table(CSV)

Tags: python, text-mining

So I'm pretty new to python and probably asking an easy question. I'm looking for a way where I can extract chapter names, section names and text from a docx file and transfer it to a table where in the first row I have the chapter name, the second row the section name, third row the text from the chapter. Another thing I want to add at some point have a new line for each new paragraph of the text. I had the following steps in mind but I doubt sincerely whether it is the right way to go:

1. Open word document

   1.a. Read word document

   1.b. Define headings, subheadings, footnotes & headers
2. Create new file

   2.a. Create table with 9 rows
3. Name each row
4. Fill in header with predefined text: Legal document

   "Part  Title   Chapter Section Subsection Article number   Article text
   Article title  Reference"
5. Define rankings of the categories

   5.a. Give rankings to the table, row 1 contains document name

   5.b: row 2 contains chapter name, row 3 section name etc.
6. Read word document from start to the first defined ranking

   6.a.: Copy the text of the defined ranking

   6.b. Append to file the copied text into the correct row

I've looked into docx and xlml but I wonder whether it will give me the result I'm looking for.

Comment: The most useful advice would be that you "start" / "attempt" something. Then once you get stuck somewhere particular, you come back. See [ask].

Answer (score 1):

You'll need the docx and CSV or openpyxl modules. You'll also need effort. Figure out a way to differentiate between the things you want to store in the CSV then throw this detection and storage into a loop that senses and stops when there is nothing more to do. That's the most advice you'll get with this type of question.